# About SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

Error report:

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
> 00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

I am getting this error and I tried a lot to solve this but it could not work please help me with this error so I can complete my project

This is my code:

```
create table Customers1
(
    cust_id number(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    cust_name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    cust_address varchar(35),
    cmp_id number (22),
    constraint Customers1_cust_id_pk
        primary key (cust_id),
    constraint Customers1_cmp_id_fk
        foreign key cmp_id References Company (cmp_id)
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `cmp_id` be in parentheses in the foreign key constraint?

Answer (score 3):

Put brackets around the columns in the foreign key constraint and you also do not need both a `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the same column:

```sql
create table Customers1(
  cust_id      number(20) NOT NULL,
  cust_name    varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  cust_address varchar(35),
  cmp_id       number (22),
  constraint Customers1_cust_id_pk
    primary key (cust_id),
  constraint Customers1_cmp_id_fk
    foreign key (cmp_id) References Company (cmp_id)
);
```